# tarfile and user,group information problem

Tags: python, tarfile

I am using python tarfile module to extract files from a *.tgz file. Here what I use:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("some.tar")
tar.extractall(".")
tar.close()
```

Assume "some.tar" contents as:

```
-a.txt ===> user:usr1 , group: grp1
-b.txt ===> user:usr2 , group: grp2
```

But after extracting I lose all of user,group,date... information. They now belong to whoever calls the script(in my case root). They become like:

```
-a.txt ===> user:root , group: root
-b.txt ===> user:root , group: root
```

Is there a way to keep file owner,date information of files?

From [tarfile module page](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html):

-`handles directories, regular files, hardlinks, symbolic links, fifos, character devices and block devices and is able to acquire and restore file information like timestamp, access permissions and owner.`

From this statement I understand that is is very well possible to do this by "tarfile" module, or do I understand it wrong?

Python version is 2.6.1

Edit: I am running this script as root

Thanks

Comment: Your edit says your are "running this script as root", but I don't think that's correct. You must be running it as "usr3:grp3", based on the ownership you saw for the extracted files. If you run it as root you should see files either owned correctly, or owned by root, depending on what version of Python you have.

Comment: i forgot to edit that part. you can assume it is root:root instead of usr3:grp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guettli says, you have to be root to be able to change the ownership of a file to somebody else. Otherwise, you open a huge security hole.  This is true when using the tar(1) program or when trying to use the tarfile package from python.

Note, though, that some earlier version of Python have a bug (see issue in comments below) that means files extracted by root are owned by root instead of the real owner (user and group).

Comment: I am sorry but no. If I call "tar" with subprocess as root then all permissions applied well. But if I run above script as root, then they all become root:root

Comment: Here's the issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue9065  -- Note that when I run your script as root on my OS X box running 2.6.1, it works correctly, so it looks like Apple fixed this in my version.

Comment: thanks for bug page. If you edit your answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

First, your script needs to run as root (on unix like systems). Otherwise, you can't use chown.

You need to get the TarInfo object for the files:

http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarInfo

There you get uid (user id) and gid (group id) and (or user name).

Then you need to use chown.

Comment: If you run this as root the tarfile package will do the chown for you. Actually, tar will do the same time if you run it from the command line.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I was thinking this must be a default behaviour. If it is not, then I can call "tar" with subprocess which will take less time for my case

@Lee-Man actually,for me, it doesn't do the same thing as "tar" on command line. After running as root, they all become root:root